# How can I change the datatable length menu option on a search button click?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net, webforms, datatables

I am utilizing the datatables length menu through javascript on my asp page and it works great where users can select how many items to show on a page. However, I want to make it so that if a user uses our search bar and clicks search that the length menu automatically changes to "All" which is a current option. I am not sure how to access the length menu options through vb, asp, or javascript.

Javascript on ASP page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        var dtable = $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID%>').DataTable({
            colReorder: true, stateSave: true,
            dom: 'Bfrtilp',
            buttons: [
                {
                    extend: 'colvis'
                },
               {
                   extend: 'csv',
                   text: 'Export',
                   title: 'Applications',
                   exportOptions: {
                       columns: ':visible'
                   }
               }
            ],
            columnDefs: [
                {
                    targets: [],
                    visible: false
                },                    
            ],
            "lengthMenu": [[15, 25, 50, 100, -1], [15, 25, 50, 100, "All"]],
            "scrollX": true
        });



        $('#divGrid').show();
        $('#divLoading').hide();

        dtable.columns.adjust().draw();

        $('#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>').focusTextToEnd();
        $('#<%=txtSearch.ClientID%>').keypress(function (e) { if (e.which == 13) { e.preventDefault(); $('#<%=btnSearch.ClientID%>').click(); return false; } });

        $(".buttons-colvis").click(function () {
            if ($(".dt-button-collection").height() > 350) {
                $(".dt-button-collection").css("height", "350px");
                $(".dt-button-collection").css("overflow-y", "visible");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: You can use [page.len()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page.len())] for this.

Comment: @KThorngren where and how can I incorporate this into my asp page?

Comment: After performing search on you button click, you need to add this line `dtable.page.len( -1 ).draw();` .

Comment: So, I assume this goes in the javascript at the top of my asp page? At this point there isn't a button click function in my js, so how can I add one that relates to my asp button? Or if there is a way to do it on the vb button click portion I would like that as well.

Comment: I tried creating a function and then calling it on client click, but it makes all the default all the time, not just when the button is clicked.

function searchclick() { dtable.page.len(-1).draw(); }

<asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" CssClass="button blue small" Text="Search" OnClientClick="searchclick()"></asp:Button>